# RGB Value Under Cursor anywhere on the screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe

My code will run and compile. It works if you are hovering anywhere inside of the JFrame, but when you get out into the screen, it will only work sometimes, and if it does, it will only take in the RGB value for white, and sometimes gray. I'm not sure why it does not work every time I go outside of the box, and why it does not get all RGB values outside of the frame, but works inside. Could someone please take a look? I have attached a screenshot with it giving white outside of the box upon hover. Thanks!

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class RGBValue {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

     new RGBValue();
}

public RGBValue() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Get the RGB");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            try {
                frame.add(new TestPane());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(RGBValue.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);                          
        }    
    });   
}

public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage img;
    private JLabel label;
    private JPanel fields;
    private JTextField red;
    private JTextField green;
    private JTextField blue;
   // private JTextArea RGB;

    PointerInfo info = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point point = info.getLocation();    
    Robot robot = new Robot();      

    public TestPane() throws Exception {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        label = new JLabel();
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://c6.staticflickr.com/2/1520/24330829813_944c817720_b.jpg");
            img = ImageIO.read(url);  
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        add(label, gbc);

        fields = new JPanel();
        fields.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        red = new JTextField(3);
        green = new JTextField(3);
        blue = new JTextField(3);
        fields.add(red);
        fields.add(green);
        fields.add(blue);
        add(fields, gbc);

        robot.delay(2000);

        label.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
          //  @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

         // while (true) {
                //int packedInt = img.getRGB(e.getX(), e.getY());
               // Color color = new Color(packedInt, true);
               point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();   
               Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int)point.getX(), (int)point.getY());
               // RGB.setText(color.getBlue() + color.getRed() + color.getGreen());
               red.setText(Integer.toString(color.getRed()));
               green.setText(Integer.toString(color.getGreen()));
               blue.setText(Integer.toString(color.getBlue()));
               fields.setBackground(color);
            } 
        });

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing only receives mouse events when the event is generated over a Swing component.

If you want to receive events anywhere on the screen then your frame needs to cover the entire screen.

You can maximize the frame by using:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

before making the frame visible.

Of course now the frame will cover the background so you won't see the desktop so you will need to make your frame transparent. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Create Translucent Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Although this is a good idea, and it does expand across the screen, it still only takes the RGB value sometimes.

Comment: @Millie, `robot.delay(2000);` - why would you have a delay? The pixel will be retrieved when the MouseEvent is generated. So the frequency of update is controlled by the mouse movement.

Comment: Taking this out does not fix it either. I'm still not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @Millie, `, it still only takes the RGB value sometimes` - I don't know what that comment is referring to 1) your original code, or 2) the modified code because you have not updated your question to show the code you are currently testing.

Comment: I mean, adding frame.setExtendedState only makes my screen full size, it does not fix the fact that my mouse can't get the RGB outside of the window.

Comment: The frame will cover the screen so there is nothing else outside the frame. I already stated, you can't respond to MouseEvent outside the bounds of your frame. I then stated you need to make the frame transparent. If you want mouse events from anywhere on the desktop then you need to write code in a lower level API like JNI (which I know nothing about).